# Quoting issues in function call

Tags: postgresql, function, plpgsql

I created the following function to validate clients in my database:

```
create or replace function altaClient(p_nombre cliente.nombre%type,p_repcod cliente.repcod%type,p_limcred cliente.limcred%type)
RETURNS varchar as $$
declare

begin
    if p_nombre in (select nombre from cliente) THEN
        RAISE 'El cliente ya está registrado';
    end if;

    insert into cliente (cliecod,nombre,repcod,limcred)
    values (nextval('cliecod'),p_nombre,p_repcod,p_limcred);
    return 'El cliente se ha dado de alta correctamente';

    if p_repcod not in (select * from cliente where repcod=p_repcod) THEN
        RAISE 'El representant no existeix';
    end if;
end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But when I try to use it I get this error:

> ```
> training=> select altaClient("Samuel S.A",101,20000.2);
> ERROR:  column "Samuel S.A" does not exist
> LINE 1: select altaClient("Samuel S.A",101,20000.2);
> ```

Any idea what the error means? I read a little and it seems I have to use execute in the function, but I'm not sure.

Comment: You forgot to declare your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL there is difference between ' and ". " uses for case sensitivity name of objects (tables, fields, and others). Please change your query to:

```
 select altaClient('Samuel S.A',101,20000.2);
```